# recursive function in problem persistence function

Tags: python

I need help with my code. It is supposed to multiply the digits in a number and tell the number of times you must multiply the digits until you reach a single digit.

example:

`persistence(39) #returns 3, because 3*9=27, 2*7=14, 1*4=4 and 4 has only one digit`

I have a problem to output the variable steps because i use a recursive fuction. I understand what is my problem but i dont know how to solve it. I know that when i call back de function my variable step start over again.how can i do to solve this?

```
def persistent(x):
    steps=1
    ans=1 
    num=str(x)

    for i in num:
        ans*=int(i)
        
    if ans>=10:
        steps+=1
        persistent(ans)

    else:
            steps+=1
            print(steps)
    

persistent(39)
```

Comment: Your ```steps``` gets reset to one every time. Move the ```steps``` outside the function and assign ```0``` to it. Then, add the top inside the function, ```global steps``` should be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about it backwards.

What do you need to actually produce? The *number of iterations*. Wouldn't it be easier, then, to count *backwards* from the base case, rather than *forwards until* the base case?

```
def persistence(x):
    st = str(x)
    if len(st) == 1: 
        # base case - return 0
        return 0
    else:
        # recursive case - return 1 plus whatever the next iteration is
        n = 1
        for digit in st:
            n *= int(digit)
        return persistence(n) + 1

print(persistence(39))
# 3
```

Also note how returning the number and printing it *afterwards* is a much easier way of carrying this information back up the stack.

---

The logic looks like this:

- call `persistence(39)`

  - call `persistence(3 * 9 = 27)`

    - call `persistence(2 * 7 = 14)`

      - call `persistence(1 * 4 = 4)`

        - return `0` (base case)
      - return `0 + 1 = 1`
    - return `1 + 1 = 2`
  - return `1 + 2 = 3`
- print the returned value, which is `3`

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of how many steps have been performed in previous recursive calls:

```
def persistent(x, previous_steps):  # take number of previous steps as input
    steps = previous_steps  # start from previous steps already performed
    ans = 1
    num = str(x)

    for i in num:
        ans *= int(i)

    if ans >= 10:
        steps += 1  # increment steps
        return persistent(ans, steps)  # recurse & tell it how many previous steps were already done
    else:
        steps += 1
        return steps  # we're done, return the total number of steps


print(persistent(39, 0))  # start with 0 since we have no previous steps performed
```

And also you should `return` the value, not `print` it

This outputs:

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that your `steps` was defined **inside** the function. Hence with each calling of the function, your `steps` was reset to 1. The solution is to move `steps` outside the function and add `global steps` inside the function.

```
steps=0
def persistent(x):
    global steps
    ans=1 
    num=str(x)
    for i in num:
        ans*=int(i)
    if ans>=10:
        steps+=1
        persistent(ans)
    else:
        steps+=1
        print(steps)
persistent(39)
```

Output:

```
3
```